Exam P Sample Problems # 30
The question:

A company establishes a fund of 120 from which it wants to pay an
amount, C, to any of its 20 employees who achieve a high performance
level during the coming year. Each employee has a 2% chance of
achieving a high performance level during the coming year. The events
of different employees achieving a high performance level during the
coming year are mutually independent.
Calculate the maximum value of C for which the probability is less
than 1% that the fund will be inadequate to cover all payments for
high performance.

The solution to this problem was provided and I do not quite understand the setup. Intuitively we could say there is an upper limit to the number of high performers for which once we cross that threshold, we will have insufficient funds to pay the bonuses with. The solution says that we want to find $x$ such that $P(X>x)<0.01$ where $X \sim \text{bin}(20, 0.02)$. Equivalently, we could find $P(X\leq x)>0.99$.
$P(X=0)=0.068, P(X=1)=0.272, P(X=2)=0.053, P(X=3)=0.006$
$P(X\leq 0) = 0.068, P(X\leq 1) = 0.94, P(X\leq 2) = 0.068, P(X\leq 3) = 0.999$
$P(X>0) = 0.332, P(X>1)=0.06, P(X>2)=0.007, P(X>3)=0.001$
Then $x=2$ is where $P(X>x)$ becomes less than $0.01$.
Therefore $C=\frac{120}{2}=60$ is the correct final answer.
The issue for me is that I cannot tell why we want to find $P(X>x)<0.01$ as opposed to $P(X=x)<0.01$ or $P(X\geq x)<0.01$.
(a) I interpret finding $P(X>x)<0.01$ as: find the number of "successes" out of 20, say c, for which the probability of getting more than c successes is less than 1%. I'm defining "success" here as "being a high performer". In other words we are finding the number of high performers, c, such that the probability of having more than c high performers is less than 1%.
(b) I interpret finding $P(X=x)<0.01$ as: find the number of high performers, c, such that the probability of having exactly c high performers is less than 1%.
(c) I interpret finding $P(X \geq x)<0.01$ as: find the number of high performers, c, such that the probability of having at least c high performers is less than 1%.
Assuming that interpretations (a), (b), and (c) are correct, I do not understand why (b) and (c) would not give us the correct answer. Can someone explain to me why, preferably in the context of this problem, (a) will lead us the solution while (b) and (c) do not?
For example, if I used interpretation (b) to setup the problem, then I would say that since $P(X=2)=0.053>0.01$, that the we need more than 2 high achievers to maintain that the probability of paying out all high performers is less than 1%. What about 3 high performers? $P(X=3)=0.006 < 0.01$. So let the number of high performers be 3, so divide 120 by 3 and we get $C=40$. I would've assumed that answer is correct without seeing the solution.
What am I not understanding here?

Welcome to CV.  Please add the "self-study" tag.

This isn't really a matter of statistics: it amounts to reading the question carefully and understanding what your notation means.  For instance, when $X=2,$ exactly two employees are paid.  When $X\ge 2,$ two or more employees are paid.  If this were your company and your money and your problem, would you be concerned only about $X=2$ or would you be concerned about $X\ge 2$?  That's what it all comes down to.

@whuber Ah I think I get it now, thanks.
